# Had images lined up with flex box side by side, but now they are not

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I had this code working, and all three of my images were side by side, and now it is back to them being stacked on top of each other. I tried adding the justify-content, and align-items. I had also tried putting width:100% under #outro img, but it still doesnt display right yet.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  #outro {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  #outro h4 {
    flex: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFE121;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 10px;
    border-top: solid 2px #FFFFF6;
  }
  #outro img {
    padding: 10px 10px;
    flex: 1;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  #outro img:first-of-type {
    flex: 2;
    order: 2;
  }
  #outro img:last-of-type {
    order: 3;
    padding-bottom: 44px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="outro">

  <h4>HOPE TO SEE YOU THERE!</h4>

  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/" alt="cos 3">

  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/" alt="cos 4">

  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/" alt="cos 5">

</section>
```

Comment: Seems to be fine in the snippet?

Comment: Check your screen size. You have a media query set. The CSS kicks in only when the min-width is triggered.